# Why does Dependabot try to authenticate to JCenter?

Tags: github, jcenter, dependabot

I have enabled Dependabot for a GitHub project of mine: https://github.com/t1/deployer

For a while now, it opens issues that it could not authenticate to JCenter, e.g. https://github.com/t1/deployer/issues/163

I don't want to provide my credentials! Why does it try to do that? I don't remember configuring it to do anything with JCenter. I didn't find any config option, nor anything useful on Google, yet.

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/g00glen00b was so nice to give me the correct hint:

> Since January 13th, JCenter is no longer available through HTTP. In
>   stead, you have to use HTTPS. This likely solves #163, since
>   Dependabot is using the  in your pom.xml to check for
>   new versions.

Now Dependabot works again!